# RSpec Ajax Test for Like Button Not Passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara

I have an RSpec controller spec that simply won't pass. I'm trying to test a like button, which is an AJAX post request, that updates the amount of likes on the show page under the post. When I physically test on localhost, I can click the like button under a post and the number of likes increments by 1, as expected. When I run my controller spec, it keeps failing with:

```
PostsController POST #vote a user can vote on a post increments the number of votes

Failure/Error: expect { post1.votes }.to change{post1.votes}.by(1)
           expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
         # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The above comes from this:

/spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rails'

RSpec.describe PostsController, :type => :controller do

  describe "POST #vote" do

    let(:post1) {Post.create!(content: "The Content created", votes: 1, story: "My story", author: "Authors Name")}

    context "a user can vote on a post" do
      it "increments the number of votes" do

        post :vote, post1: { votes: post1.votes }, 
          params: { id: post1.id },
          xhr: true

        expect { post1.votes }.to change{post1.votes}.by(1)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried a few variations of `expect { post1.votes }.to change{post1.votes}.by(1)` including, but not limited to: `expect { post1.votes }.to change{post1.votes}.from(1).to(2)`, but it's still not passing. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. I also made a feature spec that goes something like this:

/spec/features/liking_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Like feature" do

  let!(:post) {Post.create!(content: "The Content created", votes: 1, story: "My story", author: "Authors Name")}

  scenario "users can like quotes" do
    visit root_path

    click_link "Motivation"
    click_link post.author

    expect(page).to have_button "Like"
    expect(page).to have_current_path post_path(post.id)

    click_button "Like"

    expect { post.votes }.to change{post.votes}.by(1)

  end
end
```

This also fails with the same message as above.

Here is my AJAX request for clicking on "like" and the number of likes increments by 1.

app/assets/javascripts/like.js

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){

  // On click increments likes by 1. 
  $("#liking").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/vote',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id: id,
          increment: true
        },
        success: function() {
          var like_counter = $('#likeit');
          var current_count = parseInt($('#likeit').html());
          like_counter.html(current_count + 1); 
          $("#liking").hide();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

In my post controller:

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def vote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(votes: @post.votes + 1)
  end
end
```

Lastly, here is my show.html.erb where the like button is.

```
<center>
  <strong>Likes:</strong>
</center>
<center>
  <p id='likeit'><%= @post.votes %></p>
</center>
<center>
  <button id="liking" type="submit" data-id="<%= @post.id %>">Like</button>
</center>
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `expect {}.to change ...` correctly.

It is meant to be   `expect { the action that causes the change }.to change { the value that will change }.by(1)`

In your controller spec example that would be something like

```
expect do
  post :vote, post1: { votes: post1.votes }, 
     params: { id: post1.id },
     xhr: true
end.to change { post1.reload.votes }.by(1)
```

Note the `reload` call on post1, that is so when the matcher re-evaluates the value of votes after executing the post that the object gets updated.

The second issue you have is in your feature spec.  Even if you updated that to correct use of the change matcher (`expect { click_button "Like"}.to change...`) your test would most likely still fail because the vote count has not actually been updated when `click_button "Like"` returns.  This is because `click_button` triggers the behavior asynchronously and then returns.  You really shouldn't be testing DB value updates in feature tests, and instead should be checking for visible values on the page that change, however if you insist on checking DB values there, you will need to use some type of waiting matcher (https://github.com/abotalov/waiting_rspec_matchers) or sleep after the button click.

Comment: That was it! Thank you, @Thomas Walpole.
Yea, I initially had a feature spec for like, but then after reading some docs and other questions, I realized that was probably not the best way to go. That's why I switched to the controller spec. I'll most likely get rid of the feature spec as I agree that I shouldn't be testing a DB value on a feature spec.